# Ruby Selenium Automated Test Alert Window

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I'm running an automated test on Ruby/Cucumber with Selenium Webdriver on Chrome and trying to delete an object, but every time I do so, an alert window pops up and asks me to confirm. the window has the buttons "ok" and "cancel". How can I click on "ok" automated?

### Update from comments

Error stack trace:

```
unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Möchten Sie den Benutzer test@test.de wirklich löschen?} (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106) 
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) 
 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError)
```

Comment: Upgrade your chrome driver and selenium as @DebanjanB says, and then try executing the code `b.alert.ok`, it would work. `gem install watir` will install the selenium-webdriver as well, but once after the installation, just check with `gem list selenium-webdriver`, If it is not the recent one, then try installing `gem install selenium-webdriver` as well.

Comment: Link to watir documentation: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to click okay button in the alert

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept
```

This code is to dismiss the alert

```
driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss
```

My advice is to use WATIR if you are ready to use Ruby Selenium Binding, WATIR is the nice wrapper which sits on the top of Ruby selenium binding. There are many usual errors like Element not visible, Stale element error wouldn't even arise in WATIR, WATIR has the way to rescue all these errors for the specified time. So Use WATIR if you are ready to use Ruby Selenium Binding.

In WATIR, you could accept the alert by the following code

```
b.alert.ok
```

To dismiss the alert

```
b.alert.close
```

Comment: i tried this code but it doenst, work, and i'm already using watir too, do i need to change some configs or requirements? im pretty new to test auomation unfortunately. I just get: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Möchten Sie den Benutzer test@test.de wirklich löschen?}
        (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError)

Comment: @EnginTopuzoglu Okay, then there is a greater chance that that alert is not a JavaScript, Can you please update the Html code of that alert box please? You are using WATIR? Great! Add the WATIR tag please!

Comment: i cant see the html code of the alert box in devtools

Comment: Okay, can you please execute watir code `b.alert.ok` and also put sleep 4 before alert tend to raise and write this code to check whether it's a javascript alert `b.alert.exists?`, if it returns true then you are having Javascript alert or you might have had some hidden element which appears like pop up when you click the button, that's the part of the html. Can you give me the url to check?

Comment: Thanks, I used `@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
  @browser.switch_to.alert.accept`

Comment: @Engin Topuzoglu hi use WATIR, you are using selenium , you will be missing out all the advantage WATIR is giving you. Declare `@browser=Watir::Browser.new` .

Answer (score -1):

As per your comment update you are seeing the error message...

```
unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Möchten Sie den Benutzer test@test.de wirklich löschen?} (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError)
```

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.38*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

- You are using *chrome=68.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.38* and the *Chrome Browser v68.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.41**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v67-69*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.41 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.